# Angular 2/Web API not saving property state on single GET

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, angular

Working on a project with a Web API and a Angular2 front end.  GetAll() works fine, so I started working on GetById(id: number).  In this case it's fetching students.  The log call within getStudent() shows the correct values for this.student, but the log call run in the constructor shows undefined and I get a "Can't get property 'LastName' of undefined error.  I'm just trying to get that change to stay saved like it does with the array version.  I'm new to C# as of ~2 weeks ago, so it could be a less specific problem.

```
export class StudentDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    student: Student;
    id: number;

    constructor(
    private studentService: StudentService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router) {
    this.getStudent();
    console.log(this.student);
};
getStudent() {
    this.route.params
        .map(params => params['id'])
        .subscribe((id) => {
            this.studentService
                .getStudent(id)
                .subscribe(res => {
                    //student = res;
                    this.student = res;
                    console.log(this.student);
                    return res;
                },
                (err) => console.log(err),
                () => console.log("Done")
)});
};
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log in the constructor show 'undefined' because it is called before .getStudent(id) has finished to work.

Comment: Is there a way to force it to wait without converting it all to async?

Comment: I don't think so, however, you can protect your code with conditions when you call something on student to prevent errors.

Comment: You can set delay to your `console.log(this.student);` in constructor like this: `setTimeout(() => {console.log(this.student);'}, 5000);` which will force it to wait 5 seconds before executing, and that hopefully will be enough time for async call to finish.

Comment: It's a pretty big issue to have to wait at least 5 seconds everytime. Something like ' <p *ngIf="student">{{student.LastName}}</p> ' doesn't fix limits on time

Comment: @AlexisLeGalI agree, but I thought he just wanted to print results in constructor and this is a way to do it. I completely agree `*ngIf` directive is a perfect way to solve this situation when it comes to HTML template.

Comment: You both have been very helpful.  I appreciate it!